# How to manage cart data with Laravel RESTFUL (Stateless) API

Tags: php, api, rest, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce platform, I'm working on. I would want to enable visitors (guests) to add items to the cart without logging in first. I'm failing to have a cart identifier that separates guests' cart data. If it was not an API I was going to use Session. I'm failing to think of any best way to handle this scenario.

This is an eCommerce in laravel.

Comment: Why not create a cart (something like a GUID) identifier server-side, and just store that identifier in LocalStorage (or whatever local caching your client has available)? That way, you could just use the ID to update the cart.

Comment: Sounds, amazing. I have tried using Cache facade. I'm using visitors' details like IP, Browser and device name to create an identifier. This however, is not working on my live server. So in your case, how best can I go about it.